# How does the Stokes phenomenon appear in the asymptotic expansion of $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-zt}}{1+t^4} dt$ for $z \to \infty$?

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

Consider the asymptotic $z \to \infty$ behaviour of the function
$$ \tag 1 I_1(z) \equiv \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-zt}}{1+t^4} dt.$$
This converges for $\Re(z) > 0$, and the asymptotic expansion
$$ \tag 2 I_1(z) \sim \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\Gamma(4n+1)}{z^{4n+1}}, \quad z \to \infty, \,\, \Re(z) > 0 $$
is easily obtained.

I now want to extend the function $I_1$ to the region of the complex plane with $\Im( z) > 0$, and to do this I define another function $I_2$ as
$$ \tag 3 I_2(z) \equiv \int_0^{-i\infty} \frac{e^{-zt}}{1+t^4} dt
= -i \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{izy}}{1+y^4} dy, $$
which converges for $\Im(z)>0$, as wanted.
The asymptotic expansion of **(3)** is again easily shown to be
$$\tag 4 I_2(z) \sim \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\Gamma(4n+1)}{z^{4n+1}}, \quad z \to \infty, \,\, \Im(z) > 0 $$
which is identical to **(2)**.

But now I'm being told that despite the apparences, $I_2(z)$ is *not* the analytic continuation of **(2)** in the region $\Im(z) > 0$.
I don't understand how can this be the case: **(2)** and **(4)** being equal, shouldn't $I_1$ and $I_2$ coincide in the region $\Re(z)>0, \Im(z)>0$, where both are well defined?

Comment: By how you've defined it, $I_2(z) = -i I_1(-iz)$, so there is no analytic continuation being made.  By definition $I_1(z)$ is analytic on $\operatorname{Re} z > 0$, so $I_2(z)$ is analytic on $\operatorname{Im} z > 0$.  The first asymptotic in $(2)$ is valid as $\operatorname{Re} z \to +\infty$, and the second in $(4)$ is valid as $\operatorname{Im} z \to +\infty$.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: @AntonioVargas nonetheless the asymptotic expansions of the two are equal. Shouldn't this mean something? After all, I found another function which (apparently at least) is equal to $I_1$ in some region, so why shouldn't this be a valuable candidate for analytic continuation?

Comment: No, $I_2$ is simply $I_1$ rotated $90^\circ$ in the complex plane (and multiplied by $-i$).  It doesn't give you any extra information.

Comment: @AntonioVargas suppose we didn't know the actual form of $I_2$, but only that its asymptotic expansion is **(4)**. Doesn't this tell us anything about the relations between $I_1$ and $I_2$?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Different functions may have the same asymptotic expansions.